# Folder/File Options

Tags: nautilus

I'd like to use the **File Preferences** settings as someone replied on my last question, but there is NO "File Preferences" tab available in the Home Folder that pops up when I click on it in the Launcher.

Is there a keystroke combination I need to use? If so what is it?

The answer I received said "In Nautilus......"

Is there some other utility or application (`nautilus`) I need to launch to configure the GUI preferences that came with the desktop in 12.04.4?
There is a process called `nautilus` running on my laptop. It is process id `19595`, using `36.1 MB` of system RAM and priority `Normal`.

I would like to view/manipulate the directory structure in my shiny new version of Ubuntu through the provided GUI, as I can do very proficiently from the command line. I am trying to teach my children how command line operations like `ls -al` and `chmod` in the GUI are difficult, time consuming, eat power and are supposed to be for the benefit of the user.

In doing so, I am demonstrating my limitations and inexperience in this `nautilus` GUI, as well as proving my point to them that, in the long term, it is far easier and faster to learn the command line and scripting.

Comment: File Preferences is a menu item in the `Edit` menu of any Nautilus window. If you open your Home folder, it is selectable there from the menu bar. There are no shortcuts that I know of to access the settings other than through the menu item of an open Nautilus window.

Comment: There is no "Edit" menu in the Nautilus window:

Comment: I have left and right clicked EVERY location, item, box outline, icon, search box, link and NOTHING called "Edit"

Comment: Sylvain beat me to the punch - see his answer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

With Nautilus (12.04) opened, just move your mouse cursor to the top left corner of your desktop to display the title bar and its menu, then go to the Edit item:

[image]